# install gRPC and got make error

Tags: git, rpc, grpc

I want to install gRPC in my centos and i did the follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/grpc/grpc.git
cd grpc
make
```

and now make error:

```
[root@VM_8_69_centos grpc]# make
[MAKE]    Generating cache.mk
[C]       Compiling third_party/boringssl/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c
In file included from third_party/boringssl/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:66:
third_party/boringssl/crypto/asn1/../internal.h:121:22: error: stdalign.h: No such file or directory
make: *** [/root/src/grpc/objs/opt/third_party/boringssl/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

That project uses a number of git submodules--if you go into the [third_party directory on github](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/third_party) all the submodules have a grey double folder icon and if you click it takes you to another project, not into a subdirectory.

To fix the error you're seeing in `make` you probably just need to run `git submodule update --init --recursive` to check out all the submodules.